# Repair a system that is missing grep

Tags: apt, updates, grep

Due to a misunderstanding about how grep works I reinstalled grep but I continued to believe there was a problem. I later did this...

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove grep
```

and then rebooted. Unfortunately the operating system uses grep and so some things may be broken in addition to grep being absent. For example, the launcher no longer appears when the cursor is moved to the edge of the screen and the system tray which would allow selection of a WiFi connection will not appear at the top of the screen.

In an attempt to repair I did a control-alt-F1 to enter a console mode. (An alternative way to a console via control-alt-T does not work.) In the console mode I ran the following...

```
sudo apt-get install grep
```

The following appears...

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
grep
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
Need to get 153 kB of archives.
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 grep amd64 2.25-1~16.04.1
  Temporary failure resolving us.archive.ubuntu.com
```

This has been going on for about 12 hours. I have even changed physical locations. I was in a residence with WiFi and now I am in a computer repair shop on ethernet to the internet. The people here are all on Windows and know nothing about Linux.

Comment: You don't mention that any other websites are having this problem. Can you access any other sites? If so, try changing mirrors. If that doesn't work, download the grep package from https://packages.ubuntu.com/ and install it manually.

Comment: I did pings to numbers and pings to named domains related to Ubuntu updates. They worked. Since I cannot see the browser launch icon I cannot do browser based testing. I did notice some sites were intermittent before I ruined the OS. Finance.yahoo.com was intermittent.

Comment: This sounds like something way beyond just missing grep. You might want to consider reinstalling.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain the only action that ruined the OS was the purge remove of grep. I will edit the mirror list now. I am abroad now.

Comment: I too doubt that's your problem, I had a look at what `grep` installs and it's `grep: /bin/egrep, /bin/fgrep, /bin/grep, /usr/bin/rgrep` plus of course `man` page etc. Yes this will impact any tool that uses those programs, but I doubt it's your issue.  I'd `wget` the grep package (and suspect you'll get errors there) then `dpkg -i` to install - I believe it's networking issues

Comment: I agree comms is an obstacle for using apt-get to make a repair. I see packet loss. I will try to obtain the executables directly.

Comment: @guiverc I used FTP because wget did not connect. Strange. The launcher, system tray, and control alt T, and grep are now functional. If you post an answer I will select it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User @ajgringo619 (https://askubuntu.com/users/975100/ajgringo619) had highlighted that it may have been a network issue.

I looked inside the package

```
    guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   apt-file show grep
    grep: /bin/egrep                          
    grep: /bin/fgrep
    grep: /bin/grep
    grep: /usr/bin/rgrep
    -- plus redacted doc & man pages
```

and Yes those would impact any tool that used those programs, but I doubted it was your issue agreeing with @ajgringo619.

I suggested using `wget` to download the grep package (suspecting you'll get errors there) then `dpkg -i` to install.

@H20NaCl (OP) had trouble with `wget` so switched to `ftp`..

Comment: The following site has choices for the debian package for grep... https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/grep/download   There are also the Ubuntu packages for example the one that is specific to xenial...   https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/grep/download     From these sites you can formulate how to FTP or wget.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend mixing packages intended for debian on a Ubuntu system unless you're very aware of the consequences (esp. when it comes to release-upgrade time).  If you look the two you mention differ somewhat https://packages.debian.org/buster/grep vs https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/grep and debian/ubuntu packages versioning isn't identical; which is what apt/aptitude etc use to determine which is latest (not version of software within the package which may differ to debian.package version)